# Messing up with conflict between spring jcl and commons-logging.jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependency-injection, apache-commons-logging

Standard Commons Logging discovery in action with spring-jcl: please remove commons-logging.jar from classpath in order to avoid potential conflicts

I have few lines in my code that are related to spring - jcl

```java
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(BaseBatchProcess.class);
```

Java version : 17
Spring version : 6.1.5

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
          <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.1</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
          <version>2.23.1</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.23.1</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.23.1</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.23.1</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.36</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.36</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
          <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.3</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
          <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.1</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>jakarta.xml.soap</groupId>
          <artifactId>jakarta.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.1</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>jakarta.xml.rpc</groupId>
          <artifactId>jakarta.xml.rpc-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.4</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
          <version>0.2</version>
          <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
          <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>spring-jcl</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
          <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
          <version>12.2.0.1</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
          <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.3</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
          <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
          <version>1.4</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
          <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.4</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
          <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
          <version>5.5.13.3</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
          <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
          <version>6.0</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
          <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
          <version>5.20.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.2</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
          <version>2.15.1</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I tried running `mvn dependency tree - Dverbose`. But I didn't find anything on commons-logging.jar I tried using jcl-over-slf4j but still didn't work and getting this error "Standard Commons Logging discovery in action with spring-jcl: please remove commons-logging.jar from classpath in order to avoid potential conflicts
" . I am stuck here.